# Make windows vim mouse copy/paste behave like xterm/putty

Tags: linux, windows, vim, mouse, putty

My workstation is MSWindows with puTTY as my xterm/ssh client to linux servers. The way things work that I'm used to in linux is left mousedrag selects, rightclick pastes, and I wanted to be able to copy/paste between Windows, gvim, and putty. I don't know if this is the best way to do it, but here's what I put into my $HOME/_vimrc on my MSWindows workstation to make it all work:

```
set clipboard+=unnamed
set paste
set go+=a
set mousemodel=extend
noremap <RightMouse> <MiddleMouse>
noremap <MiddleMouse> <RightMouse>
```

Basically, I swapped the right/middle mouse buttons, disabled the context menu that comes up by default when you rightclick (even after swapping), enabled pasting and set the copy/paste buffer to the system one.

Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `'selectmode'`, `'mousemodel'`, `'keymodel'`, and `'selection'` options with

```
:behave xterm
```

(for your preferences) or

```
:behave mswin
```

(for the sake of others who may be reading this).  Also, make sure that `$VIMRUNTIME/mswin.vim` is not being sourced.  (Check with `:scriptnames`.  Depending on how you installed vim, there may be a system vimrc file that `:source`s this file.)  For more information, read

```
:help gui-mouse
```

Comment: Thanks -- that 'behave xterm' did wonders for some of the remaining irritations.